# Intersection Observer stops working when WebView is zoomed

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I have a simple WebView in Android. I setup Intersection Observer to let me know when elements intersect (currently I alert in JS). As I scroll I can visibly see the child/parent elements intersect and when the observer is supposed to raise an event - it does, correctly.

However, if I pinch zoom, it no longer reacts to child/parent intersects when it should.

I have also tried to build my own before through listening to scroll event. It worked fine, but once any zooming occured it would give me the wrong positional data and it would not work.

It's like the zooming happens but doesn't take the viewport size change into account.

Any ideas on what is going on here?